# Python pip update and installation errors

Tags: python, pip

Im trying upgrade pip but its error or smth i'm new at python

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (22.0.4)
```

Comment: How do you try tu upgrade pip?

Comment: I tried that : python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: The it seems as if you already have the newest version.